# Subdomain routing in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am trying to get sub-domain routing working in my ASP.NET 5 application.

I basically want to map http://api.example.com to a particular controller within my application, http://map.example.com to a different controller etc.

I have looked at various articles about this but they are all out of date and do not work with the latest version of the ASP.NET framework.

The [official documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/routing.html) is missing information on routing. Maybe it's my own fault for trying to use a beta product!

Looking forward to hearing some ideas of how to get this working.

Comment: May be you can write a `middleware` which rewrite the path

Comment: Do you have an answer for this problem? Please share.

Comment: @aguafrommars How can you achieve this with middleware?

Comment: @apero with someting like a rewrite path http://api.example.com can become http://example.com/api and you can use the default routing system based on controllers's names

Answer (score -2):

If I understand your intent correctly, ASP.NET routing is not the proper way for this.

If this was for ASP.NET versions before 5.0, I'd have suggested that you intercept the request before it's routed within Application_BeginRequest() and check for HTTP_HOST Request Header value to determine which site the user wanted to visit.

I see that the application flow has changed in a major way with vNext. However, I came across this sample from the ASP.NET MVC 6 source on github that creates a custom route based on a "User" header in the request:
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/dev/samples/CustomRouteSample.Web
I believe this may be the starting template for a similar solution to your issue if you use "HTTP_HOST" header instead.

Good luck, let us know if you're able to implement a working solution.

Comment: ASP.NET 5 does not have an `Application_BeginRequest` event.

Comment: Indeed it does not, I didn't pay attention to the version detail. I'm updating my answer accordingly.